# How does the ultrasonic sensor HC-SR04 work?

Tags: sensor

I am working on a project where I am using raspberry pi and I'm not sure whether the HC-SR04 sensor uses PCM or PWM.

Answer (score 2):

The HC-SR04 uses neither PCM nor PWM.

It is sent a short trigger pulse.  Shortly after the trigger it transmits a short burst of 40 kHz chirps and sets the (output) echo line high.  The echo line goes low when an echo is received or a timeout expires.

The round trip time to a detected object may be found by measuring the high echo pulse time.  A simple formula using the speed of sound then gives the distance.